# Friend classes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to create something like friend classes in Objective-C?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First declare a "private property" using the standard class extension method:

```
// VisualNotePlayer.h
@interface VisualNotePlayer : NSObject<NotePlayer>{
    @private
    UIView *_currentView;
}

// VisualNotePlayer.m
@interface VisualNotePlayer()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentView;
@end

@implementation VisualNotePlayer
@synthesize currentView=_currentView;
...
@end
```

Then recreate the properties in a category:

```
// VisualNotePlayer+Views.h
@interface VisualNotePlayer(Views)
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentView;
@end
```

This interface is only accessible to those who import `VisualNotePlayer+Views.h`

Comment: Ah... So you need to have several .h files for the same class effectively.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a friend class in ObjC.

And to access a private variable of another class you don't even need to be declared as a friend. For example, you can use the runtime functions

```
id the_private_ivar;
object_getInstanceVariable(the_object, "_ivar_name", &the_private_ivar);
```

to get `the_object->_ivar_name`, bypassing compiler checks.