# Friend class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am porting cpp code into Objective C.

In `cpp` we can add a class as `friend class` to another class and use all its public functions and variables.

I know that `Objective C does not support friend class` concept.

How do i make a class as a friend to another class in Objective C

Comment: @ron : check my help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241488/friend-classes-in-objective-c

Comment: Please do a search before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have two tightly-coupled classes, then you can use some simple tricks to expose a simpler public interface.  For example,

In `Banana.h`:

```
@interface Banana : NSObject
- (BOOL)isPeeled;
@end
```

In `Monkey.h`:

```
@interface Monkey : NSObject
- (void)eat:(Banana *)aBanana;
@end
```

In `BananaPrivate.h`:

```
@interface Banana (PrivateMethods)
- (void)peel;
@end
```

Then your `Monkey.m` file can import `BananaPrivate.h` to get the private functions.  If you're writing a framework, then you don't include `BananaPrivate.h` in your framework headers.

This is the same way encapsulation is done in C.  In my opinion it's significantly less broken than the `friend` keyword in `C++`, but it's beyond the scope of this answer to explain why.

You can also expose private member variables this way if you implement Banana as a class cluster, but that's kind of insane and I don't recommend it.  If you need even closer coupling between classes you might want to use C idioms for that part of the code.