# How do I only let some classes call a method and not others in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have created three classes, and one method in one of the classes, but I only want my other two classes to be able to call the method. Any guess how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Friend class in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006701/friend-class-in-objective-c)

Comment: implement `protocols` and those class will confirm to this protocol will have to methods implemention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241488/friend-classes-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in links given in the comments, a Category will get you similar behaviour in Objective-C.  The difference, compared to C++, is that it's voluntary rather than enforced by the compiler.

Any class that imports the Category header can make the call and, even if the header isn't published, a programmer can call the method if the signature is known by declaring a Category interface (or ignoring a compiler warning).

If you're doing this as a way of reminding yourself not to call those methods, Categories work well.  If you were trying to protect against someone else "hacking into" the methods, it would be little defense.