# Can you create class methods in Objective-C only visible within your library?

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, superclass, friend-class

I found [this StackOverflow question on friend classes in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006701/friend-class-in-objective-c) which was ***similar*** to the issue I'm trying to solve, but not quite the same. So I'd like to extend their example.

Suppose I want the ability to hand a Monkey multiple Bananas and he'll keep an array of all of his own Bananas. When I tell him to eat, he eats from his array. I can then ask him to give me a Banana at random:

**Banana.h**

```
@interface Banana : NSObject
- (BOOL)isPeeled;
@end
```

**Banana.m**

```
#import "Banana.h"

@implementation Banana
{
    @private
    BOOL peeled;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        peeled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)peel // PRIVATE METHOD
{
    peeled = YES;
}

- (BOOL)isPeeled
{
    return peeled;
}
@end
```

**Monkey.h**

```
#import "Banana.h"

@interface Monkey : NSObject
- (void)give:(Banana *)aBanana;
- (void)eat;
- (Banana *)getBanana;
@end
```

**Monkey.m**

```
#import "Monkey.h"

@implementation Monkey
{
    @private
    NSMutableArray *bananas;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        bananas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)give:(Banana *)aBanana
{
    [bananas addObject:aBanana];
}

- (void)eat
{
    BOOL hungry = YES;
    for (int i = 0; i < bananas.count; i++)
    {
        if (!banana.isPeeled)
        {
            hungry = NO;
            [banana peel];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hungry)
    {
        NSLog(@"Monkey ANGRY!");
    }
}

- (Banana *)getBanana
{
    int r = arc4random_uniform(bananas.count);
    return [bananas objectAtIndex:r];
}
@end
```

In this case, `Banana.h` and `Monkey.h` would be public headers in a library I'm distributing. The intended use of my library would look something like so:

**ClientApp.m**

```
#import "MonkeyLib/MonkeyLib.h"

@implementation SomeClass

- (void)someMethod
{
    Banana *oneBanana = [[Banana alloc] init];
    Monkey *oneMonkey = [[Monkey alloc] init];
    [oneMonkey give:oneBanana];
    [oneMonkey eat];
    Banana *twoBanana = [oneMonkey getBanana];
    if (twoBanana.isPeeled)
    {
        NSLog(@"No sad monkeys!");
    }
}

@end
```

The immediate issue with the code above is that my library won't compile because no interface for the class `Banana` defines a `peel` method (as utilized by `Monkey.m`)

The StackOverflow question I linked at the beginning of this question suggests creating a third header file:

**BananaPrivate.h**

```
@interface Banana (PrivateMethods)
- (void)peel;
@end
```

Then in `Monkey.m` I can import `BananaPrivate.h` and I can suddenly call the `peel` method. However this fails because when I attempt to import `BananaPrivate.h` I create a collision -- I've already defined `Banana` when I imported `Banana.h` in `Monkey.h`

I can't remove `Banana.h` from `Monkey.h`, because one of the methods on `Monkey` returns an instance of type `Banana`!

I found a quirky work-around by sub-classing `Banana` like so:

**InternalBanana.h**

```
@interface InternalBanana : Banana
- (void)peel;
@end
```

Then within `Monkey.m` I can safely `#import "InternalBanana.h"`. However this has two issues:

1. It only works for Bananas instantiated **by my Monkey** (if a user of my library instantiates a Banana and passes it to my Monkey, it will be a Banana and not an InternalBanana)
2. I have to create an `InternalBanana.m` file, but within this file I **cannot** define `peel`. Attempting to define `peel` within `InternalBanana.m` will throw an error that `peeled` is not defined, since `peeled` is a private variable of the super class. If I define `peel` within `InternalBanana.m` and it only calls `[super peel]`, that will also fail since `Banana` does not define a `peel` method. While this ***works***, it does cause Xcode to throw a warning saying that there is no method definition for `peel` (but it builds and runs despite the warning)

What is the ***proper*** solution to this monkey business?

Comment: Objective-C is a dynamic language. You can achieve this for compiling, but there’s no way you can prevent an existing selector to be called at runtime. So probably not worth wasting your time...

Comment: The `Banana (PrivateMethods)` category adds method `peel` to the existing `Banana` class. It doesn't define another `Banana` class. I tried your code and don't see a collision.

Comment: @Willeke Apparently my issue was that I removed the `(PrivateMethods)` bit. Turns out that's required, even though Xcode didn't syntax highlight it, color it, or seem to know what it was. I added it back in and it worked. Removed it, error.

Comment: Beside this: `@private` is meaningless. It only restricts the direct access to a *var*. But this is already restricted to the actual module, because you define it in the class implementation. Moreover, unrelated to your Q, `-eat` works strangely on `hungry`. It is always true.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Good catch, simple typo on my part. After eating the monkey should no longer be hungry :)