# Proper way to create friend properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

All-

What is the proper way to define friend properties in Obj-C (specific implementation is Xcode for IOS). By friend properties, I mean instance attributes that are available to the base class, any subclasses of that base, but not to the public.

example:

```
@interface Base : NSObject
@property int friend
@end

@interface Sub : Base
@end

@implementation Base
@synthesize friend;
@end

@implementation Sub
-(id)newFriend
{
[self setFriend: [someOtherObject friend]];  // this should be allowed
}

@implementation Wow
-(void)
{
Sub* sub = [[Sub alloc] init];
[sub setFriend: [someOtherObject friend]];  // this should not be allowed
}
```

I have tried putting the @property friend for Base in the .m file, but then Sub cannot see it.

In c++ I had a helper declarator called friend which did exactly what I am looking for.  How to do this in Obj-C?

Thanks

Comment: **Have a look at this post :**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241488/friend-classes-in-objective-c

Comment: Minor nitpick: in C++, what you describe is just "protected", not "friend".  "friend" is necessary if the friend is *not* a subclass.  Objective-C has @protected, but it's just for instance variables, not methods (as joerick mentions below).  Property accessors are just methods.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to enforce this behaviour in Objective-C. Properties are just getter and setter methods on the Objective-C object, and methods can be called by anyone.

One thing you can control is visibility. The way that I've emulated protected properties in the past is to declare only public properties in `Base.h`. Then create another header file called `Base+protected.h`, which contains a class extension with the declared property.

```
// Base.h

@interface Base : NSObject

@end

// Base+protected.h

#import "Base.h"

@interface Base ()

@property int friend;

@end

// Base.m

#import "Base.h"
#import "Base+protected.h"

@implementation Base

@synthesize friend;

@end

// Sub.h

#import "Base.h"

@interface Sub : Base

@end

// Sub.m

#import "Base+protected.h"

@implementation Sub

@end
```

So the Sub implementation can see the protected properties, but any external class only `#include`s `Base.h` or `Sub.h`, so cannot see them.