# is there a way to define a variable thats accessible to some classes and not others?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, variables

In objective-c, the access to variables is limited to three types which is `@public` , `@private` , `@protected` (default) and `@package` .. these access modifiers allow us to access the variable through 4 situations in order :

1- access the variable from anywhere.

2- access the variable only inside the class.

3- access the variable from anywhere in the class and its subclasses.

4- access the variable from anywhere in the framework.

my question is: is there a way to define a variable which is accessible to some classes and not others ? (i.e. customised scope for variables)

Comment: that is what Protocols give you

Comment: What OP asked, its opposite can be done by ObjC Runtime.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is C++'s `friend` keyword. [Friend classes in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241488/friend-classes-in-objective-c) discusses the topic.

Comment: It's not true , mah, it's just a workaround for simulating the solution, the way you redirected me in is using a variable with the same name without the same backend, it's different to declare a variable in a specific access modifier and use the same name in another class with another access modifiers , you actually define two variables !

Comment: You're correct however this is the closest answer available in Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class extensions to create more flexible access control:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : SomeSuperclass {
    int ivar;
}
@end

// MyClass-Custom.h
#include "MyClass.h"
@interface MyClass () {
    int anotherIvar;
}
@end
```

Now anotherIvar will be accessible only to code that #includes MyClass-Custom.h. You can create more class extensions on the same class to get additional access groups.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own setter and getter methods.

```
- (id) get_abc_value:(id)from {
if ([from isKindOfClass:[SomeRespectedClass class]]) {
return abc;
} 
return nil;
}
```